# PHP variable not displaying value

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

I am storing MySQL Query value in PHP variable, but its not displaying data. P.S: Data is available in MySQL table column.

```
 <?php 
$cmsca= mysql_query("SELECT SUM(qa_effort) FROM tbl_uat WHERE product='CAP'");
     while ($cresulta = mysql_fetch_array ($cmsca)) 
         $arra[0] = $cresulta[0];
         echo $arra[0];
?>
```

I am out of clues, what is wrong in above code? Need help!

Regards

Comment: have you tried using ``var_dump($cresulta[0]);`` to see what's in there ? Sometimes ``echo`` fail displaying some values (like ``false``)

Comment: Please make sure your query returns the result, otherwise you are doing right.

Comment: do: var_dump($cresulta) inside while loop

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this

```
   <?php 
  $cmsca= mysql_query("SELECT SUM(qa_effort) as sums FROM tbl_uat WHERE product='CAP'");
   while ($cresulta = mysql_fetch_array($cmsca)) 
   {
     echo $cresulta['sums'];
   }
  ?>
```

Comment: Answer is ok but explanation makes a answer better +1.

Comment: @Farhad the reality is i dont know what to explain :) , this basic, he is mixing between `mysql_fetch_array` and `mysql_fetch_num` .

Answer (score -1):

first of all, do not use mysql_query, - it's deprecated, use http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php instead.
Next, you need to connect to the db, before running query;

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* check connection */
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
}

$result = mysqli->query("SELECT SUM(qa_effort) as sums FROM tbl_uat WHERE product='CAP'");
while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
    var_dump($row);
}

$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

How about trying this:

```
<?php
 $arra = array(); 
 $cmsca= mysql_query("SELECT SUM(qa_effort) FROM tbl_uat WHERE product='CAP'");
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array ($cmsca)) 
     $arra = $row;
     print_r($arra);
 ?>
```